# Finite vs infinite distinction in Rudin's Analysis

Tags: calculus, analysis, elementary-set-theory

I'm starting to self-study Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*. I'm up to the second chapter, theorem 2.24.

> For any collection $\{G_i\}$ of open sets, $\bigcup_i^nG_i$ is open.
>
> For any collection $\{F_i\}$ of closed sets, $\bigcap_i^nF_i$ is closed.
>
> For any **finite** collection $G_1,G_2,\ldots,G_n$ of open sets, $\bigcap_i^nG_i$ is open.
>
> For any **finite** collection $F_1,F_2,\ldots,F_n$ of closed sets, $\bigcup_i^nF_i$ is closed.

So, the parts I find mysterious are bolded. Why would the last two proofs require the finite qualifier?

**Edit**

Sorry for not being clear. Rudin's text provides counterexamples to allowing the last two proofs to be infinite. But how do we know these such counterexamples don't exist for the first two proofs?

So I'm also asking **Why do the first two proofs not require the finite qualifier?**

Comment: In the first two, you made a transcription error. It's "For any collection $\{G_\alpha\}$ of open sets, $\bigcup_\alpha G_\alpha$ is open", and analogously for the intersection of closed sets. The last two assertions require the "finite" qualifier, because they would in general not hold for infinite collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question of topology, in which these are taken to be *axioms* defining open and closed sets. To see why they are reasonable, take a few examples:

$A_n = (-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ is an open set for every $n$. What happens if we take an infinite intersection? $$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \{0\}$$. If we allow infinite intersections of open sets to be open, then we must conclude that $\{0\}$ is an open set.

Even worse, try $B_n = (-1-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})$. The infinite intersection is $[-1,1]$. We certainly don't want this to be an open set!

You can do similar arguments to justify why you only allow finite unions for closed sets. All of this should naturally fit into your intuitive idea of open and closed sets.

For a higher-level justification, take a course in point-set topology.

Answer (score 1):

Is $\bigcap^\infty_{n=1} (-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ open? Is $\bigcup^\infty_{n=1} [-1+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}]$ closed?